# Solr - Customize Fragment

Tags: regex, highlighting, solr4

I want to use Regexp Fragmenter in my solr highlighting feature to customize my fragment.

As per requirement , we need to return 25 words before and after highlighting term.

Below is one sample highlight fragment.

`Some polls show a major gender gap between men and women when it comes to gun control. A Washington Post/ABC News poll in January showed that <span class="highclass">women</span> supported a semi-automatic gun ban by 20 more points than men. They favored a ban on high-capacity magazines by 15 points.`

To do so, I have made below regular expression

```
((?:\w+\W*){25})\b(span class)\b((?:\W*\w+){25})
```

This regular expression working fine with the simple string. (tested) , but while using it with solr, it does not seems to work properly.

Few highlights coming fine, but for few highlights , the highlight term comes in very start of highlighting fragment.

I am not sure, that regexp fragmenter can do, what I need. And is there any other ways to fulfil this requirement.

Can anybody suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0):

**[Possessive Quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)** (an extra "+") will do the trick:

```
((?:\w++\W*+){25})\b(span class)\b((?:\W*+\w++){25})
```